# Kotlin, can I get if default argument is used in the function?

Tags: kotlin

I want to know if default argument is used.
Something like:

```
private fun createVideo(path: Url = DEFAULT_PATH, width: Int = 0, height: Int = 0) {
    if (path is default value) {
        // it means caller didn't set path
        return AVideo()
    else {
        return BVideo()
    }
}
```

I am handling this with function overloading which is unefficient.

Edit: 
Here is my real code

```
  private fun createMediaItemMock(mediaType: Int,
                                    width: Int = WIDTH_2K,
                                    height: Int = HEIGHT_2K,
                                    trimmingDataCan: Boolean) = mock<PickerMediaItem> {
        on { it.mediaType } doReturn mediaType
        it.width = width
        it.height = height
        it.trimmingData = mock {
            on { can() } doReturn trimmingDataCan
        }
    }

    private fun createMediaItemMock(mediaType: Int,
                                    width: Int = WIDTH_2K,
                                    height: Int = HEIGHT_2K) = mock<PickerMediaItem> {
        on { it.mediaType } doReturn mediaType
        it.width = width
        it.height = height
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Assume `DEFAULT_PATH` is `http://google.com` then do you want to distinguish between `createVideo()` and `createVideo(Url('http://google.com'))`? This can only be done using reference equality... however I'd argue is a very bad API, reference equality shouldn't matter only the value so specifying the default value explicitly shouldn't change the behaviour of the function. (BTW: you'd also have to keep the particular instance used as default as private since otherwise an user can do `createVideo(DEFAULT_PATH)` and then it's impossible to tell the difference)

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the `path.equals(DEFAULT_PATH)`. Plus you should return something on the function if you are `return AVideo()` or `return BVideo()`

```
private fun createVideo(path: Url = DEFAULT_PATH, width: Int = 0, height: Int = 0): ReturnVideoType {
    if (path is default value) {
        // it means caller didn't set path
        return AVideo()
    else {
        return BVideo()
    }
}
```